# Is it possible to change my name in flight ticket?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, lufthansa

My name in passport is:
My name : XXX YYY 
surname : ZZZ

The name which I gave in flight ticket is:
First name : XXX
Last name : YYY
Is it possible to change my name?

Comment: When did you book the ticket? Just call the airline and tell them your situation that you have put your middle name as surname.

Comment: That depends on the airline and the type of ticket you have. If it's possible to change the name, you'll have to call the airline anyway, so why not just call and ask them if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you will fly from lufthansa:

> It is not possible to make a retroactive name change for a booking.
>
> Lufthansa provides the carriage service to the passenger named in the
>   ticket only and only against presentation of a corresponding valid
>   ticket that contains the flight coupon for the relevant flight, all
>   subsequent flight coupons and the passenger’s coupon.
>
> In the case of electronic tickets, instead of presenting the ticket
>   the electronic ticket may also be stored in the reservation system for
>   the passenger named in the booking.
>
> Your Lufthansa Service Centre will be happy to help you if you require
>   further information. If you have booked an award ticket, please
>   contact your Miles & More Service Team.

In this case, I believe that lufthansa is assuming changing the person.

Here what I found in other website:

> Name change: You cannot transfer a ticket to another person. Spelling
>   mistakes of 1-3 letters should be okay to correct. For bigger changes
>   or name changes, you will need to cancel the ticket within 24 hours of
>   booking. More details: Call the hotline on 0371 945 9747

So, I believe you need to call and explain your situation.

Source: https://www.aph.com/community/holidays/change-correct-name-airline-ticket-cost/

Answer (score -1):

In many cases, it will be possible to change the name on your ticket although a fee may apply. Contact the airline or agent that issued the ticket, and they will advise you whether or not this can be done (or if it needs to be done), together with details of any fees that will apply .